# Template taxonomy-slug.php after migration doesnt load

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, taxonomy

My template taxonomy-taxonomy-slug.php after migration doesn't work. Wordpress load another file. Maybe it is just taxonomy.php.

Lots of people here say that i must just flushing permalinks again, but for me it doesn't works.

.htaccess file is corectly. Problem must be on server side.

People say that my provider must change Apache configuration to AllowOverride All.

They answer was:

> Thank you for contacting us. You can not do this. This would allow all
>   types of directives in the .htaccess file and we can only allow some.

This diretvies are allow to changes: FileInfo, Indexes, Options=Indexes and AuthConfig.

Can I do something with this directives?

Once again. Wordpress doesn't show some error message. It just loads another php file. Maybe problem is in something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I solved my problem.

I have two types a taxonomy. One registred in function.php another in plugin. 
I delete taxonomy in function.php  and create again in plugin. Now everything works.